# How to get current date time in python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-datetime

I need to display the date and time on the browser through a variable.I am just beginner of python and flask.  Here is my code. Please suggest an idea or two to point me in the right direction.

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return date

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But it shows "internal server error"

Comment: Try `return now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: I want to return it through date variable as you can see in my code.

Comment: Is this a wrong code? date = datetime.now()

Comment: Put that line of code in your route.

Comment: Still error ..see live error at https:// pozecon.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must put the date declaration inside your route:

```
from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask
    
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    date = datetime.now()
    return str(date)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you want the date in a more presentative format replace:

```
return str(date)
```

by:

```
return date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

as others suggested in the comments

Comment: Still not working.I need a confirmation.Is datetime is a separate module or it is just part of the python/flask default installation.I Just checked in my terminal with pip command " pip list " and found no datetime thing there.

Comment: @ping pong the datetime Module is part of the Python Standard Library,so Python itself has it

Comment: So why doesn't it work? What's the problem?

Comment: what happens if you run `import datetime` at your terminal?

Comment: (python:3.7)-bash-4.2$ import datetime
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/344.
(python:3.7)-bash-4.2$

Comment: Yes it's working now.here is the live page https://pozecon.com . Thanks Brother.

Comment: Can you explain it briefly.what is "str(date)" ?

Comment: date is an object not a string and it cannot be passed to render, that is why we change it to string with str(date)